# Can we define the complex numbers without using the real numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, definition, complete-spaces

Every definition of $\mathbb{C}$ that I can think of uses $\mathbb{R}$. We can let $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with a particular multiplication. We can let $\mathbb{C}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$.

The best way I could come up with to define $\mathbb{C}$ without $\mathbb{R}$ is to let $\mathbb{C}$ be the "completion" of the algebraic closure of the rational numbers. I'm not really sure what the "completion" would mean in this case. Can anyone finish this idea, or suggest a different approach?

Comment: you can define this field up to isomorphism by the following sentence: "an algebraically closed field of characteristic 0 and cardinality 2^N0". I mean the abstract field, I am not sure how to define it as a topological field.

Comment: @A.Smith The algebraic closure of $\Bbb R(X)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @Arthur: yes, $X$ is then just some transcendental.

Comment: @HenningMakholm No complex number is transcendental over $\Bbb R$. So I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: @Arthur: No, but $\mathbb C$ doesn't know which transcendentals are _real_, so the field isomorphism doesn't need to preserve them. We're ignoring topology here, so _algebraically_ both $\mathbb C$ and the closure of $\mathbb R(X)$ are both just "the algebraic closue of ($\mathbb Q$ with continuum many independent transcendentals adjoined)".

Comment: What about the algebraic and topological closure (in either order) of the rationals with the essentially unique Archimedian valuation/norm, so pretty much what the OP proposed with a little extra detail - basically one needs Ostrovsky's theorem on rational valuations, namely that all are equivalent to the usual Archimedian one or a non-Archimedian p-adic

Comment: Norms and absolute values are defined in terms of the real numbers.

Comment: @A.Smith can't we make a bigger field with the same cardinality? What if we took the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(x)$? Shouldn't that still have cardinality $2^{N_0}$?

Comment: @A.Kriegman it will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ (not via the composite of injections $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}(x)\rightarrow \overline{\mathbb{C}(x)}$, which is not surjective, but rather via some other pretty random-looking map).

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is to **define** $\mathbb C$, you *could* do it along this path:

- Start with $\mathbb Q$.
- Algebraically adjoin a root of $x^2+1$, giving $\mathbb Q[i]$.
- Define the squared distances $d^2(p+qi,r+si)=(p-r)^2+(q-s)^2$.
- The usual definition of metric spaces wants real distances, but squared distances are still enough to define *Cauchy sequences* anyway.
- Even though $d^2$ itself doesn't satisfy the triangle equality, it ought to be possible to rephrase the usual proofs of the properties of Cauchy sequences to work with $d^2$ instead. In particular we want the sum and product of Cauchy sequences to be Cauchy, the sum of two *null* sequences to be null, and so forth.
- We can then define $\mathbb C$ as equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb Q[i]$.

I haven't done the details, but I suppose we can show reasonably painlessly that $\mathbb C$ is a field extension of $\mathbb Q[i]$.

On the other hand it could be a real challenge to prove the fundamental theorem of algebra -- that is, that our $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed -- without introducing $\mathbb R$ and its topology through a back door somewhere along the way. Withough $\mathbb R$ there would be no intermediate value theorem, for example.

Comment: I feel like we are already involving the real numbers by taking the real and imaginary parts of the inputs to $d^2$. This requires viewing $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over the reals in order to take the components.

Comment: @A.Kriegman: No it doesn't. $\mathbb Q[i]$ is created as $\mathbb Q[X]/\langle X^2+1\rangle$, and it's a simple algebraic fact that every congruence class in that ring has exactly one element of the form $a+bX$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Q$, which we also notate as $a+bi$. There is no need for real numbers in that, just rationals.